# how to pass variable javascript to php

Tags: javascript, php

I need some help, I will create chart using morris.js but i find some problem, when i use `detailIp` in pipeline mongoDB in php tag (as show bellow)  but no result show. I dont know why.
How to pass `detailIp` so it can use in php tag ?
thank before and sorry my english is so bad :(
Here my code:

```
     <script>

                    $(document).on("click", ".open-detail", function () {

                         var detailIP = $(this).data('id'); 
                         document.getElementById("header_ip").innerHTML = "IP "+detailIP;
                         document.getElementById('ip').innerHTML =detailIP;


                          Morris.Area({
                          element: 'graph1',
                          behaveLikeLine: true,
                          data: [

                          <?php 
                            ini_set('max_execution_time', 600);
                            ini_set('memory_limit', '2048M');
                            $m = new MongoClient("192.168.80.20");
                            $db= $m->blacklist;
                            $col=$db->score;
                            $cursor=$col->find(array("ip_blacklist"=>"'".detailIP."'"));
                            $detail_ip=array();
                            foreach ($cursor as $document) {
                            $detail_ip[]=$document;
                          }

                            $score=array();
                            $time=array();
                            for ($a=0; $a < sizeof($detail_ip); $a++) { 
                            $score[]=$detail_ip[$a]["score"];
                            $time[]=date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$detail_ip[$a]["timestamp"]->sec);
                          }
                            for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($detail_ip) ; $i++) { 
                                echo "{date:'".$time[$i]."',count:".$score[$i]."},";
                            }
                        ?>
                          ],
                          xkey: 'date',
                          ykeys: ['count'],
                          labels: ['Y']
                        });
                    if($('#graph1').find('svg').length > 1){
                       $('#graph1 svg:first').remove();
                       $(".morris-hover:last").remove();
                                }
                    });

</script>
```

Comment: Read up on how ajax works. php runs only on the server , not in the browser

Comment: Don't mix `php` code with `js` - it's a bad practice. You need send `detailIP` by ajax and then retrieve data from your backend or get data (still ajax) from your backend and modified them in javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do an [ajax](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp) call to pass your js varibale to your php code.
Here is an example.

```
$.ajax({
             url: "/your_controller_the_php_code/the_action_the_php_function",
             dataType: "json",
             data: {                         
                 your_js_variable: detailIP                  
             },
             success: function( data ) {
               /*this is where you do what you want to do  when you get the response from your php code*/
          }
      });
```

Hope it's helpful

Answer (score 0):

you must use ajax :

```
<script>

    $(document).on("click", ".open-detail", function () {

         var detailIP = $(this).data('id'); 
         document.getElementById("header_ip").innerHTML = "IP "+detailIP;
         document.getElementById('ip').innerHTML =detailIP;

    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: "... php file address ...",
        format : 'html',
        success: function (data)
        {


              Morris.Area({
              element: 'graph1',
              behaveLikeLine: true,
              data: [data], // <<=== data from ajax
              xkey: 'date',
              ykeys: ['count'],
              labels: ['Y']
            });
            if($('#graph1').find('svg').length > 1){
               $('#graph1 svg:first').remove();
               $(".morris-hover:last").remove();
                        }
            });

        }
    });



</script>
```

in php file :

```
<?php 
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 600);
    ini_set('memory_limit', '2048M');
    $m = new MongoClient("192.168.80.20");
    $db= $m->blacklist;
    $col=$db->score;
    $cursor=$col->find(array("ip_blacklist"=>"'".detailIP."'"));
    $detail_ip=array();
    foreach ($cursor as $document) {
    $detail_ip[]=$document;
  }

    $score=array();
    $time=array();
    for ($a=0; $a < sizeof($detail_ip); $a++) { 
    $score[]=$detail_ip[$a]["score"];
    $time[]=date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$detail_ip[$a]["timestamp"]->sec);
  }
    for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($detail_ip) ; $i++) { 
        echo "{date:'".$time[$i]."',count:".$score[$i]."},";
    }
?>
```

Comment: thank for help, finally its solve, yeah i need ajax and in php file need to json_encode and script need dataType : "json"